# Display hash anchor tags into drupal 7 menu items without modifying hooks or adding modules?

Tags: 7, routes

currently when path url in menu items are set to: `node/1#anchor` the anchor is removed.

How would you solve this?

Comment: At the least, you'll need to add a function to template.php

Comment: Why _"without modifying hooks or adding modules"_? That's how Drupal works :)

Comment: but i would imagine it should just work.. its just a # hash tag in a url. i dont see why i gotta go through all that just to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal cannot do this out of the box. However, you can use the [Special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module to create a new menu item, and place "nolink" in the path settings.